# Alert box is invisible when BACK button is pressed

Tags: android, alert, back-button

In my app, there is a button to upload pic to facebook. When this button is pressed an alert box appears to take user caption and then the pic is uploaded. Now if I press BACK button while picture was being uploaded to facebook(after caption is given and `OK` is pressed), then  I see my activity again but this time when I try to upload the pic again, I do not see the alert box (although it is there in invisible mode because if i hit at the location of `OK` button then pic gets uploaded. What is happening here ?

```
//Listener to button to upload to facebook
class ButtonListener3 implements View.OnClickListener{

        @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Pic.this.Commentbox();

    }
}


public void Commentbox(){
    value="";
    alert1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    alert1.setTitle("Write caption");


    // Set an EditText view to get user input 
    final EditText input = new EditText(this);
    alert1.setView(input);

    alert1.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
    value = input.getText().toString();
    Pic.this.fb();
     }
    });

    alert1.setNegativeButton("No, thanks", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()      {
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
       value="";
       Pic.this.fb();
    }
    });

     alert1.show();

}

    public void fb(){
final Facebook facebook=new Facebook(ID);
facebook.authorize(Pic.this, new String[] { "publish_stream" },
        new DialogListener() {

    @Override
    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(DialogError dialogError) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
        postToWall(values.getString(Facebook.TOKEN));                                              
    }

    private  void postToWall(String accessToken) {    


        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
        byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

        bundle.putString(Facebook.TOKEN, accessToken);
        bundle.putByteArray("facebookPictureData", data);
        // The byte array is the data of a picture.
        bundle.putByteArray("picture",     getIntent().getExtras().getByteArray("data"));
        bundle.putString("caption",value); 

        try {
            facebook.request("me/photos", bundle, "POST");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Picture uploaded to your facebook account successfully",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException fileNotFoundException) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Picture upload failed, try again",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (MalformedURLException malformedURLException) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Picture upload failed, try again",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (IOException ioException) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Picture upload failed, try again",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
});

}
```

Comment: You need to put the call to fb() inside an AsyncTask. Your current code will block the UI until the post to Facebook Wall is completed. 

Extend an AsyncTask and put the call to fb() inside the doInBackground() method.

Comment: @azgolfer  if i use async, and suppose user presses home button or back button after pressing the `upload` button, then will the uploading will happen or will it be aborted.

Comment: the uploading will still happen in the doInBackground() method. You can popup a progress dialog while this is happening to prevent the 'Back' button from canceling the operation.

Comment: @azgolfer is there any difference in AsyncTask and starting new thread ?

Answer (score 1):

Rotate the device to figure out whether the window is invisible (it will remain invisible) or whether there is a redraw issue (it will appear).

The redraw issue is not an Android bug, but you app's design problem.  You shoud not take actions that take many seconds on the main (UI) thread, because doing so will block redraw for the duration of the operation.

You can use the hint from @azgolfer's comment (refactor the upload to an `AsyncTask`).
Create your subclass of `AsyncTask` and perform `fb` in its `doInBackground` method. Create its instance and `execute` from the `OnClick` handler.  Use `onPostExecute` to announce a completed upload and create a `ProgressBar` for displaying progress of the task.

As it is, you have far too much code for an `OnClick` handler (in terms of duration).

Alternatively you could call `invalidate` at any time to achieve a similar effect like device rotation:

```
ViewGroup everything = findViewById (R.id.mainLayout);
everything.invalidate();
```

But that is not a recommended design and you will likely find yourself fighting the framework on multiple fronts if you decided to take that way.

Comment: @azgolfer  if i use async, and suppose user presses home button or back button after pressing the `upload` button, then will the uploading will happen or will it be aborted.

Comment: @JohnWatson - Your choice.  Not by default.

Comment: is there any difference in AsyncTask and starting new thread ?

Comment: it is a redraw issue, rotating the mobile brings the alert, could you please explain how to solve this issue ?

Comment: @JohnWatson - Expanded on the recommended approach, edited away the clumsy workaroundish approach from the answer, and added a similarly clumsy workaround to invoke a redraw in a badly designed app.

Comment: I tried the `invalidate` solution, put the code right after `alert.show()` , but it does not work. will try to learn `AsyncTask`. Thanks

Comment: @JohnWatson - sorry for that, I must be guessing wrong how the device rotation achieves the redraw.  Maybe you are lucky that you have to do it right upfront :-)

Comment: Is using new `Thread` will be any different from using `AsyncTask` ?

Comment: By the way using following code just after `alert.show()` achieves the result. `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
  setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);` I know it is a hack. Is there any concern because of this ?

Comment: @JohnWatson - if you intend to develop you app further, or run it on future Android stack versions, expect trouble and eventual undo of the hack.  Just a gut feeling. I wonder whether you already see redraw glitches because of the brief orientation change.  But your discovery is no less interesting because of that.